# Is Husserl's transcendental ego God?

Tags: existence, phenomenology, buddhism, husserl, essence

> We will eventually come up against something that cannot be varied
> without destroying that object as an instance of its kind. The
> implicit claim here is that if it is inconceivable that an object of
> kind K might lack feature F, then F is a part of the essence of K.

https://iep.utm.edu/phenom/

It seems that I cannot vary existence out of the transcendental ego. However hard I try to erase every part from it, the transcendental ego includes at least one percept; it exists. That suggests its essence is existence, which Aquinas uses to describe God or the first cause.

I think I can do so with other things. Maybe the skin of this apple is an illusion, the red apple is in fact green, so the apple is not essentially red and its redness does not essentially exist.

---

> Reality can be compared to the wood. Imagination is like the
> perception of the elephant. Duality can be seen as the elephant.

https://info-buddhism.com/Vasubandhu-Three_Natures-Garfield.html

If it necessarily exists and we cannot imagine it is a hallucination, is the transcendental ego the dependent reality that we should realise appears as, but is not, a hallucination (the piece of wood we mistake as an elephant)?

---

*I'm really confused by this.*

It may help to know what Husserl thought existence to the transcendental ego meant.

Comment: See [Husserl and the Transcendental Ego](https://iep.utm.edu/phenom/#SH5c): "He claims that, “I exist for myself and am constantly given to myself, by experiential evidence, as ‘I myself.’ This is true of the transcendental ego and, correspondingly, of the psychologically pure ego; it is true, moreover, with respect to any sense of the word ego.”" So yes, we cannot have the I without existence (this is exactly the gist of Descartes' *cogito* (be aware that Husserl writed [Cartesian Meditations (1929)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_Meditations)).

Comment: Thus, maybe we can agree that "existence" is the "essence" of the I according to Husserl; but to conclude that the I is God is,IMO, not an Husserlian conclusion.

Comment: A good comparison of Descartes and Husserl is Thomas Attig, [HUSSERL AND DESCARTES ON THE FOUNDATIONS of Philosophy (1980)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24435557): "The *cogito* should not be presupposed as being an attribute which requires the support of a substantial ego for its existence.
Rather, it should be understood as essentially constitutive in character in the sense of its being a process within which knowledge originates."

Comment: I have read a bit by and on Husserl @MauroALLEGRANZA and I believe Fink claimed that Husserl thought the TE was eternal. but most people have called Fink confused about it. by which I mean: there may be enough reason to work out ourselves whether when "I exist for myself" essentially that means I always exist

Comment: sorry if I'm goofing the place up but @MauroALLEGRANZA I reckon it all comes down to the present already being the past. is that what Aquinas says, means or should say?

Comment: The answer to clarify Vasubandhu's nondual (root) consciousness is after your above quote: *When one understands how things are, Perfect knowledge, abandonment, And accomplishment—These three characteristics are simultaneously achieved. Knowledge is nonperception; Abandonment is nonappearance; Attainment is accomplished through nondual perception. That is direct manifestation. Through the nonperception of the elephant, The vanishing of its percept occurs; And so does the perception of the piece of wood. This is how it is in the magic show...* This is a typical dialectic reasoning...

Comment: I'm sorry not sure what point you're making. are you saying "so does [ALL] perception of the piece of wood" I'm a bit lost @DoubleKnot it's quite a simple equation

Comment: non perception is not a state of no perception in any mahayana doctrine I can think of @DoubleKnot so you're putting a heterodox spin on things if that is what you mean

Comment: I'm a bit pissed off that you left a comment that made no sense to try to show the question makes no sense. it adds to the stupid on here, that's all @DoubleKnot (not calling you thick, I don't know you)

Comment: The point is Vasubandhu's nondual consciousness is what you're looking for "some internal quality that belongs to me being eternal". WP ref about his 3 [natures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasubandhu): *These are the fabricated nature, the dependent and the absolute. The fabricated nature is the world of everyday experience and mental appearances. Dependent nature is the causal process of the arising of the fabricated nature while the absolute nature is things as they are in themselves, with no subject object distinction...the absolute, reality itself is non-dual, and the dichotomy of...*

Comment: *of perception into perceiver and perceived is actually a conceptual fabrication... Vasubandhu uses the analogy of a magician who uses a magic spell (dependent nature, conceptual construction) to make a piece of wood (the absolute, non-duality) look like an elephant (fabricated nature, duality). The basic problem for living beings who suffer is that they are fooled by the illusion into thinking that it is real, that self and duality exists, true wisdom is seeing through this illusion.* It's like you think there's stupidity/smartness in duality, while in the true nondual nature there's none...

Comment: I'm still confused if you're correcting me @DoubleKnot and if so how. sorry

Comment: It won't be that easy to understand him just by reading some commentary articles about his verses and views. But one thing is clear from all these articles and references that his theory is very much like Berkeley's idealism and Husserl's phenomenology and his above nondual consciousness of the 3rd nature can be regarded as Husserl's later transcendental ego which *transcends* the usual duality. As Mahayana's [Shurangama sutra](http://www.cttbusa.org/shurangama/shurangama17.asp.html) explained" *To speak of the false is to reveal the true. But both the false and the true are false themselves*

Comment: I see what you mean now @DoubleKnot I slightly prefer my comparative philosophical musings, but thanks for the reply

Comment: Almost by definition any *comparative* musings are still within the realm of *duality*, so the thesis of any transcendental ego posits if one's ego can reach outside this seemingly boundless and firmly binding phenomenological realm constrained by all the known phenomenal laws and patterns to another transcendental ideal realm possibly with its own forms not limited by those of the previous realm any longer. In my same ref above it's depicted as *"this Samapatti that is likened to illusion, Transcend all study instantly."*...